# CSS3 Animating Full Screen

Tags: html, css, animation

- I found one very intresting example of login form:       https://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/BNNJjo
  but it's height is limited with 400px. I want to make background to be full screen. I changed heights to `100%` but I have problem with animations.

They declared as:

```
@-webkit-keyframes square {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg); }
}
@keyframes square {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg); }
}
```

`-700px` declares height where boxes that fly disapears. To make background full screen I need to change this. I tried adding `-100%` but it isn't working.

Can you help me?

Comment: Try using 100vh instead

Comment: It works, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it helped!
I'll will write it as the answer for future preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 100vh instead.

More information about Viewport Relative Lengths [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths)